# Creating border around my image that fills page

Tags: html, css

```
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:url(hex-shape.png) no-repeat center;
  z-index:99999;
}
```

My background image is an overlay for the entire page. I would like to fill the rest of the page with white surrounding the overlay image but not within it.

I am using it to frame a picture in the middle of the screen.

The idea is the page can be a full color behind the background image and still be invisible because of the border or whatever gets put around the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.overlay{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background: #{your_color} url(hex-shape.png) no-repeat center;
  z-index:99999;
}
```

Comment: This is good... but if ends up filling color inside the png image which defeats the purpose of the frame. The png is 676px in height and 600px in width.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but it doesn't work for the size of my image... I am wondering how you came up with the size of the border and the negative margin values. If you provide an equation I know I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the picture, this is an easy way to center an image in the middle:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="placekitten" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#placekitten {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    z-index: 9000;
}
#container {
    height: 500px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

The key is to make the `margin-top` equal to `-1 * height/2` and the `margin-left` equal to `-1 * width/2`. You do have to set these values manually for this to work, however.

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/kVTM8/)

Answer (score 0):

dont realy understand what you need but i think this will help

use stretch technique :

```
.overlay{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:url(hex-shape.png) no-repeat center;
  z-index:99999;
}
```

play with the top, left, right, bottom values